# When using `typedef`: Where to place array indication?

Tags: system-verilog

When using `typedef` to declare a userdefine type, then both these forms are accepted by ModelSim:

```
typedef logic logic_7_0_t [7:0];
typedef logic [7:0] logic_7_0_t;
```

However, if doing something similar based on `real` type, then 2nd format fails:

```
typedef real real_3_0_t [3:0];
typedef real [3:0] real_3_0_t;  // Syntax error by ModelSim
```

Where to place the array indication, and why the difference between `logic` and `real`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the references to duplicate answers, my conclusion is that:

```
typedef logic logic_7_0_t [7:0];  // Unpacked array of logic, which is OK
typedef logic [7:0] logic_7_0_t;  // Packed array of logic, which is OK

typedef real real_3_0_t [3:0];    // Unpacked array or real, which is OK
typedef real [3:0] real_3_0_t;    // Would be packed array of real, which is not illegal
```